Angular 18, adding dependencies to APP_INITIALIZER
I am trying to use angular v18's provider to provide a new APP_INITIALIZER with dependencies JwtService and Auth Service. here's the code snippet for the logics
export function initAuth(jwtService: JwtService, authService: AuthService) {
  return () => (jwtService.getToken() ? authService.getCurrentUser() : EMPTY);
}

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideZoneChangeDetection({ eventCoalescing: true }),
    provideRouter(routes),
    provideHttpClient(withInterceptors([jwtInterceptor])),
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: initAuth,
      deps: [JwtService, AuthService, HttpClient],
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
};

the service for JwtService:
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class JwtService {
  getToken(): string {
    return window.localStorage['jwtToken'];
  }

  setToken(token: string): void {
    window.localStorage['jwtToken'] = token;
  }

  destroyToken(): void {
    window.localStorage.removeItem('jwtToken');
  }
}

the service for AuthService:
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AuthService {
  private apiUrl = environment.apiUrl + '/Auth';
  private http = inject(HttpClient);
  private router = inject(Router);

  private _loggedInUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject<User | null>(null);
  currentUser$ = this._loggedInUserSubject.asObservable();
  isAuthenticated$ = this.currentUser$.pipe(map((u) => u !== null));

  constructor(private jwtService: JwtService) {}

  register(credentials: RegisterCredentials): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.http
      .post<{ username: string }>(this.apiUrl + '/register', credentials)
      .pipe(map((user) => user.username === credentials.username));
  }

  login(credentials: LoginCredentials): Observable<User> {
    return this.http
      .post<User>(this.apiUrl + '/login', credentials)
      .pipe(tap((user) => this.setAuth(user)));
  }

  logout() {
    this.purgeAuth();
    this.router.navigate(['']);
  }

  getCurrentUser() {
    return this.http.get<User>(this.apiUrl).pipe(tap((u) => this.setAuth(u)));
  }

  private setAuth(user: User) {
    this._loggedInUserSubject.next(user);
    this.jwtService.setToken(user.token);
  }

  private purgeAuth() {
    this._loggedInUserSubject.next(null);
    this.jwtService.destroyToken();
  }
}

the problem is when I run the application it gave me this error:

as far as I know, this error only occurs when I haven't add a provider for the services.
So then I tried to add providers:
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideZoneChangeDetection({ eventCoalescing: true }),
    provideRouter(routes),
    provideHttpClient(withInterceptors([jwtInterceptor])),
    JwtService,
    AuthService,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: initAuth,
      deps: [JwtService, AuthService, HttpClient],
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
};

And then I got a new error:

How do I resolve this issue when I try to add dependencies to APP_INITIALIZER in angular 18? Or is there an issue that I am missing at?
EDIT:
After I checked the code, it appears that the AuthService is the reason for the 'Invalid provider' Error.

Why did you add HttpClient to the deps?

@JSONDerulo I tried following https://angular.dev/api/core/APP_INITIALIZER and assume that my app is also a standalone project. Tho nothing changed and the errors are still the same

Oh I just realized that HttpClient is totally unnecessary, my bad. The main error is Invalid provider when I try to add JwtService and AuthService @JSONDerulo

After trying out the deps and providers by adding some things, and removing it; I figure out that I need to add the dependencies by using inject(). (not deps)
const initAuth = () => {
  const jwtService = inject(JwtService);
  const authService = inject(AuthService);
  return () => (jwtService.getToken() ? authService.getCurrentUser() : EMPTY);
};

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideZoneChangeDetection({ eventCoalescing: true }),
    provideRouter(routes),
    provideHttpClient(withInterceptors([jwtInterceptor])),
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: initAuth,
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
};


Aside, based on your code in the question, the argument in initAuth must be the same (type & position) as what you provide in deps. As there is no HttpClient in the initAuth arguments, so you should remove HttpClient from the deps array.

The error might be that you do not return a corresponding value. The app initializer expects a function to be returned, if that's not the case, try
 useFactory: () => initAuth,


It still gives me the same error unfortunately
